# Missing file(s) from rc.local shell script startup

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, batch-file

I am trying to run two python scripts on startup on my Raspberry Pi.

Both scripts work if I launch them with
    python script1.py
    python script2.py

They also work with a shell script in the same folder containing

```
python script1.py &
python script2.py &
```

But if I add either the individual scripts to the rc.local startup file, or the shell script, I get errors of missing files.

If I add the python scripts to startup via rc.local then it claims that text files I call in the script are missing:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo service rc.local start
My IP address is 192.168.0.4 
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "home/pi/scripts/script1.py", line 8, in <module>
    scripts.make_batch(randint(10,12))
  File "/home/pi/scripts/functions.py", line 36, in make_batch
    num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('script1_file.txt'))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'script1_file.txt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "home/pi/scripts/script2.py", line 5, in <module>
    scripts.check(3,30)
  File "/home/pi/scripts/functions.py", line 78, in check
    with open('script2_file.txt', 'r+') as followed:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'script2_file.txt'
^C
```

If I add the batch script.sh to startup that calls the python scripts then it claims they are missing.

```
pi@raspberrypi /etc $ sudo service rc.local start
My IP address is 192.168.0.4
pi@raspberrypi /etc $ python: can't open file 'script1.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'script2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
^C
```

Is this something to do with permissions? My script folder is 755 recursive.

All the files ARE there and the scripts run fine directly. This is something to do with running files within files through the rc.local startup process... but I don't know what!

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: running a script in `rc.local` has a completely different environment then when you start it from the console. for starters it will be run as `root` (and not your ordinary user), and it will *not* be started from your ordinary user's home-directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to supply the full paths to the files:

```
with open('full/path/to/script2_file.txt', 'r+')
```

The same for your second problem:

```
'full/path/to/script2.py'
```

Comment: Ah great, I gotcha... but, do I need the "with open" part in the shell script or inside the python? Inside the python scripts, right?

Comment: @joep1. yep, in the python script.